# Correlation matrix add additional column of adjusted p value

Tags: r

Following this link:http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-formatting-and-visualization.

```
library(Hmisc)
flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) {
               ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
               data.frame(
               row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
               column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
               cor  =(cormat)[ut],
               p = pmat[ut]
               )
               }

mydata <- mtcars[, c(1:7)]
res<-rcorr(as.matrix(mydata))
flattenCorrMatrix(res$r, res$P)
```

Is there any way I can add an additional column with p.adjusted with Bonferroni correction of the square the length of the row.

Comment: Do you just mean `p.adj = p.adjust(pmat[ut], method="bonferroni")`? What do you mean with "the square the length of the row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method: add additional line

```
 flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) {
 ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
 p = pmat[ut]
 data.frame(
 row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
 column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
 cor =(cormat)[ut],
 p = p,
 p.adjust=p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))
 )
 }
```

Alternative:
Use Corr.test, for symmetric matrix, it adjusted p-value automatically.